# Are braid groups known to not be linear over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, braid-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$It is known that every braid group $B_n$ embeds as a subgroup of $\GL_m(\mathbb{Z}[q^{\pm 1},t^{\pm 1}])$, where $m=n(n-1)/2$ (see [Krammer - Braid groups are linear](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2002/155-1/p03)). This is via the Lawrence–Krammer representation, proved to be faithful for all $n$ independently by Bigelow and Krammer. Thus, braid groups are linear.

My question is whether it is known that they are not linear over $\mathbb{Z}$. That is, is it known that, for large enough $n$, $B_n$ does not embed as a subgroup into any $\GL_m(\mathbb{Z})$? I haven't found any references to this being an open problem, so I'm wondering if there's just some established reason it can't happen.

Comment: I guess it's an open question (I wondered about it long ago), for $n\ge 4$. I don't remember there's a known representation that would be a candidate to be faithful.

Comment: Braid groups are subgroups of mapping class groups. [Kontsevich](http://www.ctqm.au.dk/PL/) gave a candidate representation of mapping class groups into $GL_m(\mathbb Z)$, with $m$ is about $g^g$.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's just open, and perhaps *so* open that very few people even talk about it in the literature. But I didn't know about this proposed Kontsevich representation, good to know.

Comment: Is it known if $B_n$ is not virtually special? I think there was a question whether it is even CAT(0) and I do not know if it is resolved.

Comment: see this question, answers and comments https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42836/braid-groups-acting-on-cat0-complexes

Comment: @markvs That's right, it's open whether $B_n$ is CAT(0) (it is known for $n\le 6$ though), and I think virtual specialness is open, though it's known that it can't itself be CAT(0) cubical. (Note that "CAT(0) group" always includes cocompactness.)